# Book Structure in Django

Tags: python, django, sqlite

I am currently trying to implement a book structure in Django in the model.

The structure is as follows

**Book Class:**

title

pages (this is an array of page objects)

bibliography (a dictionary of titles and links)

**Page Class:**

title

sections (an array of section objects)

images (array of image urls)

**Section Class:**

title:

text:

images (array of image urls)

videos (array of video urls)

I am pretty new to Django and SQL structuring. What my question specifically is, what would be the best method in order to make a db with books where each entry has the components listed above? I understand that the best method would be to have a table of books where each entry has a one to many relationship to pages which in turn has a one to many relationship with sections. But I am unclear on connecting Django models together and how I can enable lists of objects (importantly these lists have to be dynamic).

Comment: Can a page appear in more than one book? Seems unlikely. Similarly, can a section appear in more than one page?

Comment: You have these the wrong way round: a page should belong to a book. This is exactly the same structure as Question and Choice in the tutorial, which you should read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL has no notion of "array" - each field in a table is atomic (contains a single value) - so if you want one entity `A` to "have" many ("an array of") another entity `B` you need (at least) two tables (one for `A` and one for `B`) and a relationship between those tables. Here you can have two kind of a relationships : "one to many" and "many to many".

If an instance of `B` can only belong to a single instance of `A` - like for example the `Book` -> `Page` relationship in your case where a `Page` belongs to a single `Book` (obviously), you have a "one-to-many" relationship (a `Book` has one or more `Page`, a `Page` belongs to a single `Book`). At the database level, this is materialized by the `page` table having a foreign key field pointing to the primary key of the `book` it belongs to. In a Django model, this is done using a [`models.ForeignKey()`  field](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/fields/#foreignkey).

If an instance of `A` has many `B` and an instance of `B` can belong to many `A`, you have a many to many relationship. This could be the case for a `Book` -> `Author` relationship (an `Author` writes one or more `Book`, and a `Book` is written by one or more `Author`. At the database level, this is implemented by an additional table which will have a foreign key on 'book' and a foreign key on 'author' (and usually a "unique" contraint of both keys so you don't associate twice the same author to the same book). In Django, this is done using a [`models.ManyToManyField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/fields/#manytomanyfield) on any of the `Book` or (nb : exclusive 'or') `Author` models, and Django will create the intermediate table by itself.

So for your example, you will need:

- a "Book" model
- a "BibliographyItem" model
- a "Page" model with a foreign key on "Book"
- a "Section" model with a foreign key on "Page"
- an "Image" model
- a "Video" model

Depending on whether you want to be able to share a same `BibliographyItem` between books or not, you'll either want a ManyToMany field or a `ForeignKey` on "`Book`. In this case (and without knowing more about your project's requirements) I'd rather go for a `ManyToMany` relationship (chances are more than one book will reference a same item).

Same thing for `Image` and `Video`, you can choose to share them between sections or not.

I strongly suggest you read more (and do a couple tutorials) on relational database modeling and relational models normalization to understand the core concepts and how to properly design your models. Django's ORM is only a thin wrapper over database tables and fields so you really need to understand what goes on at the database level if you hope to do anything good.

Comment: This was super helpful. Thank you so much.

Comment: I figured it would be separate tables between the classes/items but I am not familiar with some of the built in functionality of Django.

Comment: as a follow up, if I wanted to implement page numbers that relate to the textbooks, in addition to the id entries on the table, how would you go about that?

Comment: @Peter a `page_num` IntegerField with a unique contraint on `(page_num, book_id)` and an ordering `(book_id, page_num)`. You will have to take care of the numbering by yourself. Or you could use some of the existing "model ordering" apps, cf https://djangopackages.org/grids/g/model-ordering/

Answer (score -1):

Each Django model is a class which you import in your app to be able to work with them. To connect models together you can use foreign keys to define relationships, i.e. your Page class will have a foreign key from Book. To store lists in a field, one of the ways of doing it is to convert a list to string using json module and define the field as a text field. json.dumps converts the list to a string, json.loads converts the string back to a list. Or, if you are talking about other "lists" in your question, then maybe all you need is just django's basic queryset that you get with model.objects.get(). Queryset is a list of rows from a table.